# Google Tag Manager custom event trigger not firing

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, data-layers

I'm having an issue with a server side google tag manager container. I've added events to a website and a trigger that should be fired. But it's not getting fired. See below for how I've set it up.

```js
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
  event: "dlv_view_item",
  ecommerce: {
    items: [{
      item_name: "test name",
      item_id: "test id",
      price: "test price",
      item_brand: "test brand",
      item_variant: "test variant"
    }]
  }
});
```

[image: Here you can see that it does show up on the website.]
Here you can see that it does show up on the website.

[image]
This is how the trigger is set up.

But when testing using the debug mode, I can see the event showing up on the page but the trigger is not getting fired, does anyone know what could be the cause? Thanks in advance.